# Clicking 'OK' on alert or confirm dialog through jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, click, automated-tests

I was thinking of writing some UI tests in backbone.js and jquery. They may not be the best way to do it but it's something that I was thinking about - to automate the tests without record and playback - through plain code.

The only thing that made me scratch my head using this approach is this: In some 'use-case flow' (of the execution) confirm/alert dialogs would show up. I'd like to click 'Ok' and continue the flow - is this even doable through plain javascript code? How?

Note: I do know GUI testing libraries exist, but I want to know how to do it using just jQuery/javascript code, if at all possible.

Comment: +1 for trying a different approach to UI testing

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I know if you use a standard `alert()` call you cannot trigger an "OK" click because the alert call blocks the normal JS event loop.

However you *should* be able to replace `window.alert` and `window.confirm` with your own function that does nothing:

```
window.alert = function() {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

Place these at the top of your JS before anything else is loaded and any subsequent calls to `alert()` or `confirm()` will call these instead.

Comment: hmmmm...but I'd have to make the changes all through out the code. Those alerts are not debugs but actual part of the application, in it's early increment. They will be changed to custom alerts later...this wouldn't be possible I guess

Comment: no, the point is you just make this change once if you're in debug mode, and that code above _replaces_ all subsequent invocations of `alert()`.

Comment: Ahhhh I see! Sweet...can the same be done for confirm? I'm guessing a yes... :)

Comment: The Selenium web application testing system does exactly this.  It also records the alert, confirmation, or prompt, and lets you verify that you got the one you expected, not something else (*i.e.*, "User deleted.", not "Object not found in line 25.").  Google for Selenium and getAlert for some pointers.

Comment: So simple and yet was so elusive :)

Comment: @RossPatterson: Yes I'm aware of Selenium, I wanted to dodge the learning curve and see if I could quickly 'code one up' to verify that nothing is broken when I make some changes - which was being done quite frequently. The learning curve w.r.t., Selenium was far more than the amount of time it'd take me to code it up :)

Answer (score 3):

You want something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var oldConfirm = confirm;
var oldAlert = alert;

confirm = function() {
    return true;
};
alert = function() {
    return true;
}

var response = confirm("Is this OK?");

if (response) {
    alert("Yay");
}
else {
    alert("Boo");
}

confirm = oldConfirm;
alert = oldAlert;
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it would help...could you augment the 'intent' with some explanation please? :)

Comment: Yes, sorry.  window.confirm and confirm refer to the same thing.

Comment: I understood the intent of your code after alnitak clarified a few things :)