# How to confirm a window.confirm with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, userscripts

I need to click "ok" in a window confirmation box that will predictably appear in a certain point of my userscript execution. Usually when I needed to do that, I've simply looked at source code at executed wathever the window confirms:

e.g.

```
...onclick="DoWathever()">
```

Then I would call native DoWathever() and bypass the confirmation window. The problem is, in the function under the blankets that is calling the window.confirm, so I can't bypass using this simple way.

That being said, I already looked on stackoverflow and google for possible solutions, and found that one: [Clicking 'OK' on alert or confirm dialog through jquery/javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705817/clicking-ok-on-alert-or-confirm-dialog-through-jquery-javascript)

Which basically suggests me to override the default confirm by creating a "fake" window.confirm, using that:

```
window.alert = function() {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
    return true;
};
```

Now that's when it gets weird, I had two kinds of experience using this solution:

1) If I simply declare it manually at the console (I usually do that to test before actually including it in the script) it will work perfectly and confirm the dialog box.

2) If I include it on the script (Before everything else, mind you) it won't work, and javascript will ask me with a confirmation window, as always.

So... yeah, any ideas why it doesn't work in 2) or any possible alternative solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: I imagine it's due to the sandboxing of your extension. You aren't binding to the same ``window`` function in 1) and 2). If you want to bind to the ``window`` function in the context of the page you will have to [inject your script in to the page](http://voodooattack.blogspot.com/2010/01/writing-google-chrome-extension-how-to.html).

Answer (score 0):

In userscripts, `window` does not refer to the same thing that the page-level `window` refers to, so you'll need to do this:

```
unsafeWindow.alert = function() {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
    return true;
};
```

Read the dangers on [`unsafeWindow`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow) before you do though.